# Python + Selenium: How to find elements by using contains(text(),'') if some words contains space and some words not

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a page like below:

```
<td>Apple</td>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>Apple</td>
```

I use this code to find out all elements that contains Apple:

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*td[contains(text(),"Apple")]')`

but sometimes the page will change to below:

```
<td>Apple   </td>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>   Apple</td>
<td>  Apple       </td>
```

So, How to find out all elements that contain Apple (even if the word have spaces).

Comment: contains works for word with spaces and without.

Answer (score 0):

**Contains function in XPath is used when there is partial attributes value of an element to be match.**

Exa.

```
<td> Hello ! Welcome to Stackoverflow. </td>
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Welcome")]')
```

> By referring 'Welcome' keyword, We can achieve target element with the
>   help of contains keyword.

So your xpath should work as expected.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*td[contains(text(),"Apple")]')
```